# Synonyms for "knowing someone well"

Tags: synonyms

What word can I use to say that I know someone really really well? It's more than
"aquainted with".

Comment: Seems kind of obvious, but "friend"?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. If you are looking for a word you should generally provide an example sentence where you want to use it. Furthermore, include some basic research and explain why the dictionary synonyms are not sufficient for you. You can have a look at the [Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good questions.

Comment: This question was automatically flagged as low-quality because of its length and content.
Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Comment: "close friend"...

Answer (score 1):

[Intimate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/intimate_1):

> an intimate friend is someone who you know very well

Comment: Beware though that intimacy can often imply romantic relationships, depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

A very close relationship between two men: **like brothers**, two women **like sisters** or man and woman **like brother and sister**.

Answer (score 0):

[Familiar](https://www.google.com/search?q=familiar%20definitions&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=#q=familiar%20definition):

> well known from long or close association.